# entityManager Query returns null (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, firebird, jpa, запрос, null

мой **Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="craft_curent" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:sprinter_curent"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SYSDBA" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.documet.myapp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("craft_curent"); //sprinter
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");        
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver mr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        mr.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return mr;
    }


}
```

класс в котором пытаюсь получить данные из БД

```
 public class Otgruzka {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public String getDocumetn(){
        String ss;

try {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select SNAME from AGENTS where id=11");
        ss = (String) q.getSingleResult();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return ss;
    }

}
```

запрос возвращает null (в таблице значение есть)

```
 черв. 08, 2016 5:24:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8805 ms
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.documet.myapp.otgruzka.Otgruzka.getDocumetn(Otgruzka.java:39)
    at com.documet.myapp.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

не могу понять в чем ошибка. Все вроде правильно.

Comment: В `Persistence.xml` нет маппинга класса Агента.